# Can I programatically define a class with private fields and methods without eval?

Tags: javascript

The [MDN docs for private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) mention:

> It is a syntax error to refer to # names from out of scope. It is also a syntax error to refer to private fields that were not declared before they were called, or to attempt to remove declared fields with delete.

Outside of private fields, I can define a function which returns a constructor which can then be invoked as a class:

```
function CtorCreator(...) {
   const CtorBeingCreated = function Whatever(...) {...}
   // programmatically manipulate CtorBeingCreated
   return CtorBeingCreated
}

const Ctor = CtorCreator(...)
const instance = new Ctor();
```

In this I can programmatically define fields and methods based on arguments passed to the `CtorCreator` function. For example

```
...
   CtorBeingCreated.prototype[...] = ...
...
```

Can I also define private fields and methods that way? E.g. some way to allow me to do

```
   ...
   addPrivateFieldToCtor(CtorBeingCreated, <field-name>, <initial-value>)
   // or 
   addPrivateMethodToCtor(CtorBeingCreated, <method-name>, <method-body>) // method body can access <field-name> previously defined  
   ...
```

Comment: AKAIK this is not possible. Private fields have to be defined within the `class` body and can also only be accessed by functions that are defined in that class body. Otherwise, you could add functions to this class later to access these fields, which would defeat this functionality.

Comment: No, you can't. Why would you want to do that? What is your use case?

Comment: [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) in javascript does not support it

Comment: Can you show some more details of what and how you create that `function Whatever(...) {...}`?

Comment: @Bergi I want arbitrary access in there, that's why I've left it unspecified.